# Memory leak or not?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks

I have this small piece of code in the middle of a larger code:

```
int *p = new int[100];
p += 50;
delete []p;
```

Will the compiler delete only the memory from the 51<sup>st</sup> location? I think it does. However, in the case of array pointers, the compiler holds an additional item which tells the number of objects allocated. So, in that case, shouldn't it go ahead and delete memory beyond the allocated size?
Or does it delete the 51<sup>st</sup>–100<sup>th</sup> elements and keep the 1<sup>st</sup>–50<sup>th</sup> in the memory, in which case a memory leak can happen.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. It might leak. It might also crash or erase your hard drive.

Comment: Or start a rogue process and make an archeologist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. [The C++ standard says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

> **3.7.4.2 Deallocation functions**
>
> 3 ... Otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned
>   if the value supplied to **`operator delete(void*)`** in the standard library is not one of the values returned
>   by a previous invocation of either **`operator new(std::size_t)`** or **`operator new(std::size_t, const
>   std::nothrow_t&)`** in the standard library, and the behavior is undeﬁned if the value supplied to **`operator
>   delete[](void*)`** in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of
>   either **`operator new[](std::size_t)`** or **`operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)`** in the
>   standard library.
>
> 4 ... The eﬀect of using an invalid pointer value
>   (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undeﬁned. (On some implementations, it causes a system-generated runtime fault.)

Comment: I suddenly wonder: may an implementation of `new` and `delete` provide *more* guarantees, or does the fact that it is marked as *Undefined Behavior* means that even if an implementation of `delete` could recover from a pointer within the structure, the compiler could mess it up ? It seems to me it could (it's undefined after all, not unspecified), and I wonder if any compiler has logic that would actually mess it up; I know some compiler are able to elide `malloc`/`free` call pairs when the buffer is unused for example, so they definitely trudge in those waters.

Comment: Undefined Behavior means that the standard does not tell the compiler vendors what should happen. The compiler may actually generate code that will deallocate the 51st to 100th array element. It might also crash your program, or simply mess something up horribly. It might also delete your porn folder. It's undefined behavior, after all :) That being said you'll probably find no implementation that will deallocate half of the array. Mostly you'll either see a crash or a silent bug which can make anything happen.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually undefined behavior. You can only `delete` / `delete[]` what you got from `new` / `new[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not allocate or delete memory, it is OS-dependent what happens if you call free on a pointer value that you did not get from new.  The only thing that is guaranteed is that it is wrong.

Comment: True, but this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong. It is not the OS. This is the runtime library (usually bundled together with the compiler) which provides the memory handling facilities (`malloc` and `new`) in general. And throw some magic the `new` can overriden by the user.